# Change "Passwords match" and "Password Strength" text on signup

Tags: 7, users

How do I change the "Password Strength:Weak" and "Passwords Match:no" text on the sign up page. Are there drupal settings for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two sentences are set by Javascript (/modules/user/user.js) so for this you have to use JS too..

```
$(".password-strength-title").val("Test");
```

can replace the first one, but for the other it is more complicate. I have to look deeper.

EDIT

The info are [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_form_process_password_confirm/7) now I don't know if it is possible to do an alter

EDIT

Ok so for doing what you want 2 steps:

```
function your_module_element_info_alter(&$type){
  $type['password_confirm']['#process'][] = 'your_module_form_process_password_confirm';
}
```

Then alter the data:

```
function your_module_form_process_password_confirm($element){
  $element['#attached']['js'][1]['data']['password']['strengthTitle'] = t("Test Title");
  $element['#attached']['js'][1]['data']['password']['confirmTitle'] = t("Test confirm");

  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the source for [user_form_process_password_confirm](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_form_process_password_confirm/7), you will see the strings defined and that they are wrapped in a [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/t/7).  This means they can be translated and/or overridden.

There are a few ways to do string overrides.

The easiest way is with the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.  This lets you do everything from the UI.

You can also do it with your `settings.php` file.  If you search for "String overrides:" in that file, you will see an example, but you could do something like:

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'Password strength:' => 'Your password security is ',
  'Weak' => 'horrible.',
  'Fair' => 'pitiful.',
  'Good' => 'tolerable.',
  'Strong' => 'awesome.',
);
```